# Create a temp table that consolidates start and end dates plus generates a uniqueid for each consolidated record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, view, rank

I have a table called `projecthistory`,
it is actually a view so I could take advantage of the `Rank` function to get a unique record number.

From this view I need to create a temp table that has a `uniqueid` field which would be calculated bases on these rules:

1. Rule 1 - The next sequential record for the id changes from one
   project to another or
2. Rule 2 - If the id and project match for the next sequential record
   , but the days between the end date of the current record and start
   date of the next record for the is more than 7 days.

It would also consolidate the start and end dates appropriately for each group.

I believe this would be best done in a stored procedure that can call the data when needed, but I'm fairly new to stored procedures.

Here is an example of the table data, as well as the desired output

`Projecthistory`

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Record ║  Id  ║ Project ║   Start   ║    End    ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║      1 ║ 1111 ║ A       ║ 1/1/2016  ║ 1/7/2016  ║
║      2 ║ 1111 ║ A       ║ 1/10/2016 ║ 1/20/2016 ║
║      3 ║ 1111 ║ B       ║ 1/21/2016 ║ 1/25/2016 ║
║      4 ║ 1111 ║ A       ║ 1/26/2016 ║ NULL      ║
║      5 ║ 2222 ║ A       ║ 1/1/2016  ║ 2/1/2016  ║
║      6 ║ 2222 ║ B       ║ 2/2/2016  ║ NULL      ║
║      7 ║ 3333 ║ D       ║ 1/15/2016 ║ 2/1/2016  ║
║      8 ║ 4444 ║ B       ║ 2/10/2016 ║ NULL      ║
║      9 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 2/1/2016  ║ 2/5/2016  ║
║     10 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 2/20/2016 ║ 2/27/2016 ║
║     11 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 2/28/2016 ║ 3/10/2016 ║
║     12 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 3/11/2016 ║ NULL      ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

`Desired output`

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ unique ║  Id  ║ Project ║ ProjectStart ║ ProjectEnd ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1111A1 ║ 1111 ║ A       ║ 1/1/2016     ║ 1/20/2016  ║
║ 1111B1 ║ 1111 ║ B       ║ 1/21/2016    ║ 1/25/2016  ║
║ 1111A2 ║ 1111 ║ A       ║ 1/26/2016    ║ NULL       ║
║ 2222A1 ║ 2222 ║ A       ║ 1/1/2016     ║ 2/1/2016   ║
║ 2222B1 ║ 2222 ║ B       ║ 2/2/2016     ║ NULL       ║
║ 3333D1 ║ 3333 ║ D       ║ 1/15/2016    ║ 2/1/2016   ║
║ 4444B1 ║ 4444 ║ B       ║ 2/10/2016    ║ NULL       ║
║ 5555A1 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 2/1/2016     ║ 2/5/2016   ║
║ 5555A2 ║ 5555 ║ A       ║ 2/20/2016    ║ Null       ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Here are some notes about the desired output and some of
more difficult scenarios in this data.

Take note that records 1-2 became `1111A1`, 
record 3 becomes `1111b1`,
record 4 became the second instance of that project for id 1111 so its `uniqueid` became `1111A2`, be careful this doesn’t get lumped
in with records 1&2.

Record 9 become `55555A1` and because of the date gap
between records 9&10, record 10-12 became `uniqueid` `5555A2`

I look forward to any solutions, feedback or questions. I’m
truly grateful in advance.

Comment: Ok. I think I figured it out, but its really slow. Takes about 30 seconds to run against 3000 projecthistory records, but I do get the results I'm looking for. One thing I did forget in my initial question, was the location field.

Answer (score 1):

ok I think I got it. I was able to get the results I was looking for using the following code, but it is slow when executing it to get the results. One thing I forget, was the location column, so I was sure to account for this in my code. I did end up breaking the uid and instance into two separate fields, but I know I could have merged them into one. I figured this would give me greater flexibility when pulling data against it in the future. Feel free to improve, I know I would appreciate it. I'm also happy to be posting my first answer. Thanks!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProjectTracking]
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @max int
    DECLARE @i int 
    Declare @tinstance int
    Declare @tuid varchar(20)
    DECLARE @puid varchar(20)
    Declare @pinstance int
    DECLARE @pid int
    DECLARE @pproject varchar(10)
    DECLARE @plocation varchar(10)
    DECLARE @pstart datetime
    DECLARE @pend datetime
    DECLARE @cuid varchar(20)
    Declare @crecord int
    DECLARE @cid int
    DECLARE @cproject varchar(10)
    DECLARE @clocation varchar(10)
    DECLARE @cstart datetime
    DECLARE @cend datetime

    select @max = count([Record])+1 from [ProjetHistory] 
    print @max

    -- Insert the first record so there will be a previous record for the first cycle of while                  
    SELECT * INTO #PTEMP
    FROM (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),[id])+[project]+rtrim([location]) as Uid,1 as instance, [id],[project],
                        [location],[Start],[End]
      FROM [ProjectHistory]
      WHERE [RECORD] = 1) As x

    select @tuid = [Uid],@tinstance = [instance] from #PTEMP where [instance] = 1
    set @i = 1

    While @i < @max 
    BEGIN --Begin while
        SELECT @puid=[uid],@pinstance = [instance], @pid = [id],@pproject = [project],
                        @plocation = [location], @pstart=[ProjectStart], @pend = [ProjectEnd] FROM #ptemp
        Where [instance] = @tinstance and [uid]=@tuid
        Select @crecord =[record], @cid = [id], @clocation = [location], @cproject = [project], @cstart = [Start], @cend=[End]
        from [ProjectHistory] where [record] = @i
            SET @cuid = CONVERT(varchar(15), @cid)+@cproject+@clocation
        IF @pid = @cid
        Begin --First check if its the project instance
            IF(@cuid = @puid and DATEDIFF(day,@cstart,@pend)<=7)
            Begin --this happens if its the same project period
                update #PTEMP set [ProjectStart] = @cstart, [ProjectEnd] = @cend where [Uid] = @puid and [instance] = @pinstance
                set @i=@i+1
                set @tinstance = @pinstance
                set @tuid = @puid
            END -- done with updating existing project instance
            ELSE
            BEGIN  -- Since it didnt match pervious record must be new project instance
                select @tinstance = COUNT([instance])+1 from #ptemp where [uid] = @cuid
                insert into #PTEMP ( uid, instance,id, project, location, ProjectStart, ProjectEnd)
                values(@cuid,@tinstance,@cid,@cproject,@clocation, @cstart,@cend)
                set @i=@i+1 
                set @tuid = @cuid
            End -- Done with the new project instance for same id
        END -- Done with same id
        ELSE -- this is a new id so insert uid for id project combo
        begin -- new id so need to insert first record
            select @tinstance = COUNT([instance])+1 from #ptemp where [uid] = @cuid
            insert into #PTEMP ( uid, instance,id, project, location, ProjectStart, ProjectEnd)
            values(@cuid,@tinstance,@cid,@cproject,@clocation, @cstart,@cend)   
            set @i=@i+1
            set @tuid = @cuid 
        END -- Done inserting new record for next id
    End -- End While    

    select * from #ptemp

    drop table #PTEMP

    END
```